# NSTimer with block -- am I doing it right?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block

The following is my Objective-C category on NSTimer to do block-based firing of NSTimers. I can't see anything wrong with it, but what I am getting is that the block I pass into the `schedule...` method is being deallocated despite me calling `copy` on it.

What am I missing?

```
typedef void(^NSTimerFiredBlock)(NSTimer *timer);

@implementation NSTimer (MyExtension)

+ (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
    NSTimerFiredBlock blk = timer.userInfo;
    if (blk != nil) {
        blk(timer);
    }
}

+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds 
                                    repeats:(BOOL)repeats 
                                   callback:(NSTimerFiredBlock)blk 
{
    return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                          userInfo:[blk copy]
                                           repeats:repeats];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think `(void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer` should be an instance method `-`, not a class method `+`. The same probably applies to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`, but I am less sure about that.

Comment: That would not be the case. NSTimer scheduled methods are class methods.

Comment: Passing `self` as the target strongly suggests an instance method. All code samples of `NSTimer` that I've seen use instance methods for selectors as well.

Comment: Class objects are first class objects in Objective-C. No reason why "self" can't point to a class. That you have not seen it does not mean it is not supported. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-BAJCDADF).

Comment: Just curious, if you pass something other than a block (say, an instance of your own object with `dealloc`) for `userInfo`, does your `dealloc` gets called?

Comment: I tried your code, and it works like a charm. I put a `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:YES callback:^(NSTimer* t){ NSLog(@"I'm here"); }];` call in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and I am getting the `I'm here` logs every second.

Comment: Works great, definitely odd calling with self, but it is actually fine.

Answer (score 35):

I found this code over at `http://orion98mc.blogspot.ca/2012/08/objective-c-blocks-for-fun.html`

Great work

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.7
      target:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ /* do this! */ }]
      selector:@selector(main)
      userInfo:nil
      repeats:NO
];
```

Comment: Wow, this is great.  From experimentation, if I don't hold a reference to the NSTimer, it looks it lives until it fires and then gets cleaned up.

Answer (score 8):

You have a project on github that does the job !

[Cocoapod BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit), allow you to Blockify a bunch of Classes...

```
#import "NSTimer+BlocksKit.h"
[NSTimer bk_scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 block:^(NSTimer *time) {
       // your code
    } repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Swift version of [Mc.Stever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24790468/2094275):

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.7, target: NSBlockOperation(block: {
    /* do work */
}), selector: "main", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Swift 2.2: NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.7, target: NSBlockOperation(block: {
            /* do work */
        }), selector: #selector(NSOperation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is that if the block you're passing in is on the stack then `copy` will do exactly what the name says — it'll create a *copy* of the block over on the heap. You'd therefore expect no change in the behaviour of the one you passed in; nobody new is retaining it. The copy will stay alive while the original is deallocated.

(aside: if you're not using ARC you'll also want to autorelease the copy; you're meant to pass a non-owning reference as `userInfo:`. Otherwise the copy will never be deallocated)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
typedef void(^NSTimerFiredBlock)(NSTimer *timer);

@interface NSObject (BlocksAdditions)

- (void)my_callBlock:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end

@implementation NSObject (BlocksAdditions)

- (void)my_callBlock:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSTimerFiredBlock block = (id)self;
    block(timer);
}

@implementation NSTimer (MyExtension)

+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds 
                                    repeats:(BOOL)repeats 
                                   callback:(NSTimerFiredBlock)blk 
{
    blk = [[blk copy] autorelease];
    return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds
                                            target:blk
                                          selector:@selector(my_callBlock:)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:repeats];
}

@end
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this solution and I m still getting the same problem. I don't think it's that selectors are not supported on class methods. Class objects are also first class objects in Objective-C.

Comment: selectors definitely support class methods. your problem is block get  deallocated before timer fired but i cannot see why this is happening. what is the error message?